# How can I query based on a difference in a column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, group-by

I was wondering how can I query a column to check if there is a delta in that column. Below I have a table of cars and their prices and I was wondering if there was a way to write a query where I see the cars that match in title but differ in price. Below is what my table looks like and the current query I am using.

```
select titles, price from cars_scrape where titles LIKE ANY(ARRAY['% Ford Flex', 'Ford Flex', '% Ford Flex %', 'Ford Flex %']);

              titles               | price 
-----------------------------------+-------
 2009 Ford Flex 4dr Limited AWD    | 5995
 2011 Ford Flex Limited w/EcoBoost | 9500
 2016 Ford Flex SEL                | 21178
 2016 Ford Flex SEL                | 21637
(4 rows)
```

I have not been able to write a query to return just the 2016 Ford Flex SEL Row based on the price difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can `group by titles`, and use a `having` clause to filter on groups that have more than one distinct price:

```
select titles
from cars_scrape 
group by titles
having min(price) <> max(price)
```

If you want to actually display the offending records, one option is to use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        cs.*, 
        min(price) over(partition by titles) min_price,
        max(price) over(partition by titles) max_price
    from cars_scrape cs
) t
where min_price <> max_price
```

Comment: Awesome, I am super new to SQL is there a way to view the two entries? the above query returns a table that contains titles that have price differences (I think, still learning so sorry about this)

Comment: @dmc94: sure, see the second query in my answer.

Comment: that query gives me an error is there a specific Postgres version I have to be on?

Comment: @dmc94: my bad, I forgot to declare the table alias. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `exists`:

```
select cs.*
from cars_scrape cs
where exists (select 1
              from cars_scrape cs2
              where cs2.title = cs.title and cs2.price <> cs.price
             )
order by cs.title;
```

You can include your `where` clause in the outer query (that is part of your query but not mentioned in the question).